# Apps Script for merging data from all Google sheets in a folder into a master Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, merging-data

How do I correct this AppsScript code (written by someone else) to merge data from all Google sheets (form responses from various google surveys with the exact same questions) in a named folder into a master sheet with headers and without lots of blank lines?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Refresh data', 'mainFunc')
      .addToUi();
}

function mainFunc(){
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var header = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, activeSheet.getLastColumn()-1).getValues()[0]

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var combinedData= [];
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    if(file.getMimeType() === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      var data = getDataFromSource(file.getId(), header);
      Logger.log(data)
      data = data.map(function(r){return r.concat([file.getName()]);});
      combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);
    }
  }

  activeSheet.getRange("A2:AA2000").clearContent();
  activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData);
}

function getDataFromSource(ssId, header){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  var firstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var data = firstSheet.getRange(1, 1, firstSheet.getLastRow(),     firstSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var pos = []
  for(var i=0; i<header.length; i++){
    var colIndex = data[0].indexOf(header[i])
      pos.push(colIndex)
  }
  data.shift()
  var processedData = shiftColumns(data, pos)
  return processedData
}

function test(){
  var old_arr;
  var new_arr;

  old_arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 2, 6, 4],
    [4, 2, 3, 4],
    [9, 2, 7, 4]
  ];
  new_arr = shiftColumns(old_arr, [3, 0, -1, 2]);
  Logger.log(new_arr);
}

function shiftColumns(rows, pos) {
  return rows.map(function(cols) {
    return pos.map(function(i) {
      if(cols[i])
        return cols[i];
      else
        return ""
    });
  });
}
```

I copied the code from another sheet that works and the only changes made where the FOLDER_ID and SHEET_NAME to the relevant folder and the master sheet name on the new document.

It seems to run (execution started and execution completed appear in the execution log) but only a few lines of random data that appear on the sheet with no headers and lots of blank lines in between.

The source data for the original sheet that I copied this from is laid out in the same way (form responses from a Google survey) and displays it correctly on the original master sheet.

Very new to Apps Script, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not using a formula approach, `Importrange` and then you might a `Query` to it in order to select specific collumns (if needed).

Comment: If you are using Array Formulas in any of the Class Sheets then you cannot use getLastRow() method to get the last row.  You will have to roll one of your own.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  You need to dive into the problem yourself and ask specifics questions as you run into problems.  We don't wish to spoon feed you.  You have to try to digest the problem on your own first.

Comment: Thanks Nabnub, that is the workaround I was using but new surveys are being added to the folder daily and I can't keep up.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, that might be one of the issues. I'll check it out. First time posting so apologies for such a broad question.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues in the original code, but primarily capturing empty cells and ranges.

Here is a revised version:

```
function onOpen() {

  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  ui
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Refresh data', 'mainFunc')
    .addToUi()

}

function mainFunction() {

  const SHEET_NAME = ``
  const FOLDER_ID = ``

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME)

  const sheetHeaders = sheet
    .getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .flat()

  sheet
    .getDataRange()
    .offset(1, 0, sheet.getLastRow()-1)
    .clearContent()

  const folderSheetData = getSheetsDataObject(FOLDER_ID)

  sheetHeaders
    .forEach((header, colIndex) => {

      if (folderSheetData[header]) {

        const columnData = folderSheetData[header]

        sheet
          .getRange(2, colIndex+1, columnData.length)
          .setValues(columnData)

      }

    })

}

function getSheetsDataObject(folderID) {

  const files = DriveApp
    .getFolderById(folderID)
    .getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)

  let filesData = []

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    const [headers, ...sheetData] = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById(files.next().getId())
      .getSheets()[0]
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues()

    const sheetValuesByHeader = sheetData
      .reduce((data, row) => {

        headers.forEach((header, index) => {
          if (row[index] === ``) return
          if (!data[header]) data[header] = []
          data[header].push(row[index])
        })

        return data

      }, {})

    filesData.push(sheetValuesByHeader)

  }

  const consolidateData = filesData.reduce((data, fileData) => {

    Object.keys(fileData).forEach((header) => {
      if (!data[header]) data[header] = []
      data[header] = [...data[header], ...fileData[header]]
    })

    return data
  
  }, {})

  return consolidateData

}
```

Commented:

```
function mainFunction() {

  // Insert your IDs.
  const SHEET_NAME = ``
  const FOLDER_ID = ``

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME)

  const sheetHeaders = sheet
    .getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .flat()

  sheet
    .getDataRange()
    .offset(1, 0, sheet.getLastRow()-1)
    .clearContent()

  // Get all data from sheets in folder, organized by { "Header": [...rows] }
  const folderSheetData = getSheetsDataObject(FOLDER_ID)

  // For each header of primary sheet...
  sheetHeaders.forEach((header, colIndex) => {

    // If the current sheet header exists in the data from other sheets..
    if (folderSheetData[header]) {
      
      // Get the row data for this header..
      const columnData = folderSheetData[header]

      // and set it to the current column's index.
      sheet
        .getRange(2, colIndex+1, columnData.length)
        .setValues(columnData)

    }

  })

}

function getSheetsDataObject(folderID) {

  // Get all Sheets in specified folder.
  const files = DriveApp
    .getFolderById(folderID)
    .getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)

  let filesData = []

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    // Get headers and values of the Sheet..
    const [headers, ...sheetData] = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById(files.next().getId())
      .getSheets()[0]
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues()

    // Convert sheet values to { "Header": [...rows] }
    // (For each row..)
    const sheetValuesByHeader = sheetData.reduce((data, row) => {

      // (For each sheet column - identified by header..)
      headers.forEach((header, index) => {
        // (If cell is blank, skip.)
        if (row[index] === ``) return
        // (If this header has not been added to the result, add it.)
        if (!data[header]) data[header] = []
        // Add the current row/column cell value.
        data[header].push(row[index])
      })

      return data

    }, {})

    // Add this Sheet's data to the collection.
    filesData.push(sheetValuesByHeader)

  }

  // Consolidate all Sheet data into one big object.
  // (For each Sheet..)
  const consolidateData = filesData.reduce((data, fileData) => {

    // (Get each header of this Sheet..)
    Object.keys(fileData).forEach((header) => {
      // (If this header doesn't exist yet in the final result, add it.)
      if (!data[header]) data[header] = []
      // (Add this Sheet's column data for this header to the final result.)
      data[header] = [...data[header], ...fileData[header]]
    })

    return data
  
  }, {})

  return consolidateData

}
```

I used snippets from one of my projects, so if you have any errors please let me know and I'll help you as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks, I tried your version and I got this error message 'Exception: The number of columns in the range must be at least 1.' for line 22  .getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()) The surveys should have the same number of questions should I just bypass the 'getLastColumn' and add a number instead?

Comment: @BigMac is your main sheet empty? That line requires you to have column header values (your questions) already filled in

Comment: Additionally, if your main sheet has no values below the header row, you can comment out the following line (`sheet.....clearContent()` line of code), as it will give you an error. Once your sheet has values, you can uncomment it.

Comment: Hey @BigMac, any luck?